# How to print an Array of strings after passing it to another function

Tags: arrays, c

After receiving a certain number of students and their names, the program stops after passing it to another function to print it. How do I change this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STUDENT 1024

void print_name(char* surname,char* first_name,int n_students)
{
    int i,b=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s, %s\n",b,first_name[i],surname[i]);
        b++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n_students,i,b=1;
    char surname[MAX_STUDENT][20],first_name[MAX_STUDENT][20];

    printf("number of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n_students);

    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. ",b);
        scanf("%19s %19s",&surname[i],&first_name[i]);
        b++;
    }
    print_name(surname,first_name,n_students);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Slightly off topic: you should learn about structs.

Comment: mopheadkim, 1) Why not use all of the good answer of your 1 hour earlier question?  2) Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i know but im only using what our professor has taught us yet and structs isnt one of them yet.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i actually forgot to post that with a function so i asked again

Comment: mopheadkim, The prior one has the same unfixed problem as this one.  Many of your code problems with emit a warning when 1) all warnings are enabled, 2) using a good compiler. Faster then posting on SO.

Answer (score 1):

1. Match types between function arguments and what are passed. In main, you are passing 2D-arrays as arguments of `print_name` function , but the you are using character pointers as arguments in definition of `print_name` function
2. Remove `&` from arguments of `scanf()` to pass data having correct type and avoid *undefined behavior*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STUDENT 1024

void print_name(char surname[][20],char first_name[][20],int n_students) /* fix 1 */
{
    int i,b=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s, %s\n",b,first_name[i],surname[i]);
        b++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n_students,i,b=1;
    char surname[MAX_STUDENT][20],first_name[MAX_STUDENT][20];

    printf("number of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n_students); /* note: & here is necessary */

    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. ",b);
        scanf("%19s %19s",surname[i],first_name[i]); /* fix 2 */
        b++;
    }
    print_name(surname,first_name,n_students);

    return 0;
}
```